# ExtJs 4.2 - Cancelling/clearing the animations chain for a component

Tags: javascript, animation, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I'm building a web app and there's a part where if a button is clicked, this animation chain will execute:

```
var textReference = Ext.getCmp('splashText');
var checker = Ext.getCmp('arrow');

var img;

//for some reason, the logic is flipped
if(checker){
    img = Ext.getCmp('arrow');
}
else{
    console.log('checker is defined');
    img = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        header: false,
        style: 'background-color: transparent; border-width: 0; padding: 0',
        bodyStyle: 'background-color: transparent; background-image: url(graphics/arrow_1.png); background-size: 100% 100%;',
        width: 70,
        id: 'arrow',
        height: 70,
        border: false,
        bodyBorder: false,
        frame: false,
        cls: 'noPanelBorder',
        x: textReference.getBox().x - 90,
        y: textReference.getBox().y - 10,
        shadow: false,
    });
}

img.show();

var origW = img.getBox().width,
    origH = img.getBox().height,
    origX = img.getBox().x,
    origY = img.getBox().y;

//go down
Ext.create('Ext.fx.Anim', {
    target: img,
    duration: 500,
    delay: 0,
    from: {
        x: textReference.getBox().x - 90,
        y: textReference.getBox().y - 10,
    },
    to: {
        y: origY + 180,
        opacity: 1,
    }
});

//bounce up 1st
Ext.create('Ext.fx.Anim', {
    target: img,
    duration: 500,
    delay: 500,
    from: {
    },
    to: {
        y: origY + 50,
    }
});
//fall down 1st
Ext.create('Ext.fx.Anim', {
    target: img,
    duration: 500,
    delay: 1000,
    from: {
    },
    to: {
        y: origY + 180,
    }
});

//bounce up 2nd
Ext.create('Ext.fx.Anim', {
    target: img,
    duration: 500,
    delay: 1500,
    from: {
    },
    to: {
        y: origY + 100,
    }
});

//fall down 2nd
Ext.create('Ext.fx.Anim', {
    target: img,
    duration: 500,
    delay: 2000,
    from: {
    },
    to: {
        y: origY + 180,
    }
});

//fade out
Ext.create('Ext.fx.Anim', {
    target: img,
    duration: 1000,
    delay: 3500,
    from: {
    },
    to: {
        x: textReference.getBox().x - 90,
        y: textReference.getBox().y - 10,
        opacity: 0
    }
});
```

It's just a basic animation where a "ball" will drop, then bounce up and down that makes it look like its bouncing up then down twice before staying at the bottom, then fades out.

It's working well, however, if the user clicks on the button over and over again while the previous animation chain is still animating, the animations will compound and the calculations for the positions will get compounded, making the ball appear much lower than it should.

To prevent this, what I want to happen is once the button gets clicked, the whole animation chain gets cancelled first, then the animation starts from the top. This is to ensure that any existing animation will get halted and then a fresh sequence will get started.

Does anyone have any idea on how to execute this? I've tried `stopAnimation()` but nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with ball dropping lower and lower is that you define original Y as `textReference.getBox().y - 10` and then you try to move it to a different original Y + 180. Set your original Y first as `textReference.getBox().y - 10` and then just use it for window placement, start of the aniamtion and other animation parts.

Secondly, you should use `img.animate()` instead of

```
Ext.create('Ext.fx.Anim', {
    target: img,
```

If you do that, you can then use the `stopAnimation()` method you mentioned.

Example code:

```
var windowId = 'basketBallAnimation';
var img = Ext.getCmp( windowId );

// Set whatever you want here and use it
var originalX = 30;
var originalY = 30;

if( !img )
{
    console.log('creating new image');
    img = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        header: false,
        style: 'background-color: transparent; border-width: 0; padding: 0',
        bodyStyle: 'background-color: transparent; background-image: url(//ph-live-02.slatic.net/p/6/molten-official-gr7-fiba-basketball-orange-4397-1336487-66ec7bf47676dee873cbb5e8131c4c1f-gallery.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%;',
        width: 70,
        height: 70,
        id: windowId,
        border: false,
        bodyBorder: false,
        frame: false,
        cls: 'noPanelBorder',
        x: originalX,
        y: originalY,
        shadow: false,
    });
}

img.stopAnimation();
img.show();

// go down
img.animate({
    duration: 500,
    from: {
        x: originalX,
        y: originalY,
    },
    to: {
        y: originalY + 180,
    }
});

// ...
```

Working fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1q5f).

Other off-topic comments on your coding style:

- There's no need to save the image window to 'checker' and if the 'checker' exists to call `Ext.getCmp()` again, it saves time just to get the image and create it, if it is not saved.
- Generally use variables more to store your data instead of calling the same method numerous times (`textReference.getBox().x - 90` is called three times just in your small snippet. If you ever want to change it, you have to look really carefully where else it is applied).
- If at all possible, avoid defining any style in ExtJS. Add `cls` configuration with CSS class and apply your styles in separate CSS file.